stuct.unpack() to read hex dump file data in different order
I am using struct.unpack() to read a hex dump file and convert it to its binary representation since only a few bits are of interest to me. Below is an example of one read.
    bin(struct.unpack('<H', binary_bytes[20:22])[0])[2:].zfill(16)
I know that data is packed in uint16 format and hence I am reading two bytes. For this particular piece of code I get '0101100101111101' as the return value.
Now I need to split it to read 3 different values. It is predefined that value_1 occupies 7 bits, value_2 7 bits and value_3 1 bit.
    value_1 = 125 (1111101)  
    value_2 = 50 (0110010)  
    value_3 = 1 (1)

How do I get the formula to return 1111101011001010?
I think the hex dump file was coded with C but I am using python to decode it.
To summarise:
My input (raw hex data):
b'\x11\x0e\x0e\x0b\x04\x0e\x89\x05\x00\x00\xa4\x93\xd6N\xa4\x93VNE\x01}Y\x906\x00`\x18\x06\x00'


Code to decode this particular segment:
bin(struct.unpack('<H', binary_bytes[20:22])[0])[2:].zfill(16)
Expected output:
    value_1 = 125 (1111101)  
    value_2 = 50 (0110010)  
    value_3 = 1 (1)


Step1: Split original binary data into chunks.
original_bin_data = b"0101100101111101"
original_dec_data = int(original_bin_data,2) # 22909
splited_bin = lambda bin_data, splitter: [int(bin_data[i*splitter:i*splitter+splitter],2) for i in range(int(len(bin_data) / splitter) + (len(bin_data) % splitter > 0))]
splitter = 7
value_1,value_2,value_3 = splited_bin(original_bin_data,splitter)
print(original_dec_data,f'{original_dec_data:b}')

Output:
value_1 = 44
value_2 = 95
value_3 = 1

Option 1: left shift operator.
dec_data1 = (value_1<<9)+(value_2<<2)+(value_3)
bin_data1 = f'{dec_data1:b}'
print(dec_data1, bin_data1)

Option2: f-string formatting: more info is available in official documentation on Formatted string literals and Format Specification Mini-Language.
bin_data2 = f'{value_1:07b}{value_2:07b}{value_3:02b}'
dec_data2 = int(bin_data2,2)
print(dec_data2, f'{dec_data2:b}')

Output in both cases:
22909 101100101111101


Originally I get binary hex data. I need to divide it into chunks of 4 bytes and read only those bytes the lower endian way. Is there a way to unpack the data directly to binary format?

@Maze could you please provide the raw Hex data in your question and the expected output.
Or alternatively  create separate question in order to keep it as simple as possible so more people can help you as well.

@Maze, I've also noticed that in the past you haven't expected any answers.
The rules are simple, if the answer was useful for you then if you could either accept it or at least up-vote the response. That way people would have more incentive to help you in the future and other users would get to the solution quicker.

@Good_Man: Thanks for your inputs! I have added the hex data with an edit clarifying my input, the code I have to use and the desired output.
In the past, the answers on the question haven't. But will be more active to reply to them! Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer for another question from Maze: "Originally I get binary hex data. I need to divide it into chunks of 4 bytes and read only those bytes the lower endian way. Is there a way to unpack the data directly to binary format?"
original_hex_data = "597D"
original_bin_data =  f'{int(original_hex_data, 16):b}'.zfill(16)
splited_bin = lambda bin_data, splitter: [bin_data[i*splitter:i*splitter+splitter] for i in range(int(len(bin_data) / splitter) + (len(bin_data) % splitter > 0))]
bit_size = 8
print(splited_bin(original_bin_data,bit_size))

Output:
['01011001', '01111101']

